# sys.event_log in Azure database select query times out

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I need to diagnose some issues in production but I cannot query the event_log, query times out. 
I was trying to executing the following query on Master database in my Azure database,

```
select * from sys.event_log where start_time>='2016-02-20:12:00:00' and end_time<='2016-02-20 12:00:00'
```

Query starts executing, and runs over more than 8 mins and Cancels query execution. I am pretty sure that the eventlog must be a very large one in this database server. How to overcome this situation and query the sys.event_log table? 
Even the top 10 query times out. Need some help!

Comment: this shouldn't happen , looks like something going wrong. Could you please email your server name to snarlap at microsoft com. We will investigate the issue. Thx!

Comment: Please use this query for deadlocks:

 https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5426573e-29f6-4403-a9d9-40c9ac56ba0e/checking-deadlocks-in-azure-sql-v12?forum=ssdsgetstarted&prof=required

Answer (score 0):

Query I ran was, this might also get a time out, just keep trying (worked for me in the 3rd time)

```
SELECT *
  ,CAST(event_data AS XML).value('(/event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetime2') AS TIMESTAMP
  ,CAST(event_data AS XML).value('(/event/data[@name="error"]/value)[1]', 'INT') AS error
  ,CAST(event_data AS XML).value('(/event/data[@name="state"]/value)[1]', 'INT') AS STATE
  ,CAST(event_data AS XML).value('(/event/data[@name="is_success"]/value)[1]', 'bit') AS is_success
  ,CAST(event_data AS XML).value('(/event/data[@name="database_name"]/value)[1]', 'sysname') AS database_name
FROM sys.fn_xe_telemetry_blob_target_read_file('el', NULL, NULL, NULL)
WHERE object_name = 'database_xml_deadlock_report'
```

This gives very useful details in the xml data field.
Use an XML viewer to view details. I used [XMLGrid.](http://xmlgrid.net/)

It will show what are the two processes (deadlock victim and winner) and the good news is that it gives you the SQL statements those processes were trying to execute.

In my case two processes were trying to update one data table, but two different rows. Winner process was using a SQL "Merge" which creates a table lock for the row update. Solution was I changed that Merge query to use SQL UPDATE.